# How to get CFBundleIdentifier when lauching app on iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, methods, ios11, cfbundleidentifier

I am trying to read out the self.CFBundleIdentifier when user opens an app from Springboard.

Does someone know the method(s) and header(s) required to get CFBundleIdentifier when launching app on ios11?

Thanks in advance
Thewaytozion

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, but you can read `bundleIdentifier` from `NSBundle` share instance ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1418023-bundleidentifier)). Something like this `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to write a tweak which checks when the user opens an app and in case of a specific bundle ID it should fire another action. My question is which header, method to use to trigger a app on ios11 will be opened?